# Why do you use the request-ip module in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanted to know why you use the `request-ip` module in expressjs when you can use `req.ip` ? Thanks for the response!

Comment: tl;dr: use the request-ip module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request-ip` checks much more than just `req.ip` and you don't have to write the code yourself. See [how it works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip#user-content-how-it-works)